# Requesting someone to reply

Tags: politeness, correspondence

I have sent some emails to someone but haven't received any reply yet. In a formal/polite letter, I want to tell him that I am waiting for your reply if you have seen the emails. Which one is better

> a)  I'd like to make sure that you have seen my previous emails because I didn't receive any reply. 
>   b) I want to know if you have received my emails since I didn't get any feedback. So please reply.

Comment: Related [question](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10203/what-is-appropriate-email-follow-up-etiquette-after-no-response). This type of question may be more appropriate at http://workplace.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about email etiquette.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> a) I'd like to make sure that you have seen my previous emails because I didn't receive any reply.

The "because" part in this one is just a little awkward. This is a *cause-and-effect* statement; I'd rephrase it so that the *cause* comes before the *effect*:

> **I didn't receive any reply, so I'd like to make sure that you have seen my previous emails.**

---

> b) I want to know if you have received my emails since I didn't get any feedback. So please reply.

The only thing I don't like about this one is the abruptness of "So please reply" as a standalone sentence. The wording is fine, but I'd change the punctuation:

> I want to know if you have received my emails since I didn't get any feedback, so please reply.

That said, we might be able to make this a little clearer by reordering the events in the sentence again:

> **I didn't get any feedback, so please reply, since I want to know if you have received my emails.**

---

Of the two rephrasings I have put in bold, I think the second one reads  a little more polite. I don't think the first one would be perceived as rude, but it does have a more "pushy" overtone.

Answer (score 0):

It's primarily opinion based and there could be many ways asking it. However, I'd prefer writing this...

> Dear X, When shall I expect a reply of my previous mails? I hope they did not escape from your inbox.

Many times, it happens. The mail providers (especially Gmail) is very strict and clear in their spamming algorithm. The mails might have skipped and marked automatically as spam that the user does not know.

This'll make three things - (1) make him aware of that you already wrote mails (2) you are waiting for the reply (3) check the trash/spam by chance the mails have gone there (and if so, he'll then mark them as to be kept in inbox).